# How should I store information about rooms in a pygame game?

Tags: xml, pygame, storage

I have created a game in pygame where each room is a class in a file. If you for example go through a door in room 1, the program will create an instance of the room 2 class and run it. This might not be the optimal way of doing this, but I can't think of anything better.

But. I've been storing the information about the rooms in xml files until now. The top part of the xml file would store information about the room (like a config)

```
<bg_image>sprites\bg.png</bg_image>

<music>sounds\bg_music_2.mp3</music>
<music_start_time>1</music_start_time>

<player_x>4</player_x>
<player_y>4</player_y>
```

and the second part would store objects like this.

```
<stairs>
    <type>stairs</type>
    <posx>352</posx>
    <posy>300</posy>
    <direction>n</direction>

    <messageoninteract>There are sounds from the recorder (space)</messageoninteract>
    <amount>1</amount>
</stairs>

<deskchair>
    <type>compchair</type>
    <posx>75</posx>
    <posy>57</posy>
    <direction>n</direction>

    <messageoninteract>This chair does fit!</messageoninteract>
    <amount>1</amount>
</deskchair>

<desk1>
    <type>desk</type>
    <posx>75</posx>
    <posy>35</posy>
    <direction>s</direction>


    <messageoninteract>There's this new spoon throwing trend on youtube now.</messageoninteract>
    <amount>1</amount>
</desk1>
```

I'd loop through the xml files using xml to dict and spawn objects with according information. This worked pretty well. However, now I want to change objects in previous rooms. For example, I would like a motion in room 4 to make the table in room 2 disappear. This is really complicated and stupid with the way I've currently set up my program.

I was thinking about using configparser, but I do not understand how I'd go about making the objects then. And it's important that they are changeable, which they are not (easily) if they are embedded in the room files or even as modules.

So how should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just load all data at once into memory (use classes or simple dicts) and then change them. Do not load every room again from disk when you enter it.

You can use keys (e.g. simple strings) to reference other rooms.

Here's a very simple example to give you an idea:

```
rooms = {
    'Secret Room': {
        'bg_image': 'kitchen.png',
        'music': 'some_music.ogg',
        'on_enter': 'You found the secret room!!!',
        'north': {
            'room': 'Kitchen'
        }
    },
    'Kitchen': {
        'bg_image': 'kitchen.png',
        'music': 'some_music.ogg',
        'on_enter': 'This seems to be the kitchen.',
        'north': {
            'room': 'Living Room'
        },
        'south': {
            'room': 'Secret Room',
            'door': {
                'state': 'locked'
            }
        }
    },
    'Living Room': {
        'bg_image': 'living_room.png',
        'music': 'some_other_music.ogg',
        'on_enter': 'A nice looking living room.',
        'south': {
            'room': 'Kitchen'
        },  
        'items': {
            'old living room table': {
                'type': 'desk',
                'use': {
                    'message': 'You find a remote control and push the button!\nSuddenly, you hear a lock open.',
                    'action': 'Kitchen-south-door-state-open'
                },
                'discovered': False
            }
        }
    }

}


DIRECTIONS = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west')
running = True
current_room = 'Kitchen'

while running:
    print 'You are in the ' + current_room
    new_room = current_room
    room = rooms[current_room]
    room_directions = filter(lambda d: d in room, DIRECTIONS)

    discovered_items = filter(lambda i: room['items'][i]['discovered'], room['items']) if 'items' in room else None

    options = 'look / {0}'.format(' / '.join(room_directions))

    if (discovered_items):
        options += ' / use'

    command = raw_input(options + ' : ')

    if command == 'look':
        # list all items in the room and mark them as discovered
        if 'items' in room:
            print 'You see: '
            for item in room['items']:
                print item
                room['items'][item]['discovered'] = True
        else:
            print 'You find nothing interesting here.'

    elif command in room_directions:
        # changing the current room, if there's no locked door
        if 'door' in room[command]: 
            if room[command]['door']['state'] == 'locked':
                print 'The door is locked!'
                continue
        new_room = room[command]['room']

    elif command.startswith('use '):
        # using items by running the their action 
        item = command[4:]
        if item in discovered_items:
            print room['items'][item]['use']['message']
            keys = room['items'][item]['use']['action'].split('-')
            current = rooms
            while keys:
                key = keys.pop(0)
                if len(keys) > 1:
                    current = current[key]
                else:
                    current[key] = keys.pop()
        else:
            print 'You cannot use that.'

    if new_room != current_room:
        print rooms[new_room]['on_enter']
        current_room = new_room
```

[image]

Of course, for anything other than this simple demo you probably want to use better data structures than simple dicts. A room class with a method `get_discovered_items` should be easier to maintain than lines like `filter(lambda i: room['items'][i]['discovered'], room['items']) if 'items' in room else None`, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so simple when pointed out, this definitely works much better.